# Get a unicode value of a character

Tags: objective-c, unicode, nsstring, ascii, nsstringencoding

I have a character being entered by the user in a textfield and as per the functionality I have in my code, the system should append the same character at the end of a string. So if the user enters '$', the system adds '$' so I get '$$' on the textfield.

I want get the unicode or ascii value of the '$' character entered by the user. How do I check for it?

Comment: For all but the most complex Unicode characters:  `unichar theChar = [textString characterAtIndex:0]; int theCharIntValue = (int) theChar;`.

Comment: Sorry if I am being dumb, but is there any difference between unichar and unicode?

Comment: "Unicode" is an international character standard. `unichar` is a Cocoa [Touch] data type defined as `unsigned short`.

Comment: BTW - not all Unicode characters can be represented by a single `unichar` variable. Any character with a Unicode value of `\U10000` or greater won't fit in a `unichar`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to get the Unicode value of the character for what you are trying to accomplish. Implement the appropriate `UITextFieldDelegate` method and see if the text ends with `$`:

```
if ([someString hasSuffix:@"$"]) {
    // add another dollar sign
}
```

Comment: Well I am using the delegate method and inside it I am checking if user entered text = '$' then append string '$'. When I look on the device, both look slightly different to me. The appended string '$' looks little bit thicker/fat than the user entered '$'. I was trying to check unichar's of both of them, but I found them to be same.

Comment: If you could think of anything else I need to check or compare for this, then I would appreciate you suggesting. Thanks!! :)